# state activation in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, state

it seems my state gets activated without using $state.go. any idea why?

I have on a home page a template with links like so:

```
<a href="/abc/example?topic=car1"> volvo</a> <br/>
<a href="/abc/example?topic=car2"> benz</a> <br/>
<a href="/abc/example?topic=car3"> ferrari </a> <br/>
<div ui-view="result"></div>
```

I have defined in my config a state which matches those urls above.

```
.state({
    name="result", 
    url=/abc/:type?topic,
    template: "<div> car template {{ carName }}</div>",
    controller: "carController"
})
```

1)Now, when i click on a link it actually loads the car template. 
I am not using $state.go - 
why?? does it internally realize that it matches the url of a state and therefore loads it?

2)Interestingly, when I paste the result url link without clicking on a link on my home page, it does not seem to load the  controller, and i get the curly braces showing on my template. any idea why?

Comment: Why ? because router works on href also. If it's not working when you open in address bar yourself it is probably due to incorrect server side configuration for html5 mode. What errors are thrown?

Comment: @charlietfl thanks! well, it does not throw any error actually, it just shows the html with angular curly braces, even when i bruteforce and write ng-app="carController" inside my html ( which i am not supposed to do since it already is defined in the config)

Comment: Ok check dev tools network and see if scripts are actually loading. Sounding more and more like server side config issue or you are using relative paths to resources

Comment: @charlietfl no it does not load any javascript, in fact in the Name column in Networks in dev tools,  it only shows the url of the page fetched from the server i guess, and some image files. but thats it

Comment: Ok probably using relative paths for your scripts. Keep in mind you now have virtual directories in the url so relative path on main angular page is different than when you try to load `/abc/example`

Comment: ok, so what should i do? you re saying that when this url is pasted, it first goes to the server and fetches and returns whatever matches that routing configuration as a response, and somehow only my html is returned and not my scripts?

Comment: if script src looks like `"jsdirectory/myScript.js"` browser will now be requesting from `/abc/example/jsdirectory/myScript.js"`. if that's right put a leading `/` in front to make it root relative. You can see in dev tools network where requests are made to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177451/discussion-between-unixvanxcel-and-charlietfl).

Comment: try to use `ui-sref`: `<a ui-sref="result({topic: 'car1'})">` etc

Comment: @charlietfl the scripts load fine now but curly braces still show no actual value and are unresolved but only when pasting the link- when coming from home page href click the curly braces get resolved